# Looking for a mobile web solutions that doesn't rely on a dropdown menu to show a list of tags and add a new tag to a group

Tags: mobile-web, autocomplete, tags

Looking into alternatives than using auto-suggest dropdowns for looking up a database of existing tags and adding that selection to an existing group of selected tags. I'm looking for a solution that would be more web mobile friendly. Thanks!

The main thing is to do so without a dropdown if at all possible. Otherwise, something like Stack Exchange's tag editor is pretty nifty

I've attached an example of how the current tags work.

[image]
Result
[image]

Answer (score 1):

A pattern apps use that works quite well is bringing up an overlay that allows users to apply tags. It's quite flexible as it can be multi-select or single-select, and you can include search functionality as well. Here are 3 examples from gmail, Notion, and You Need a Budget:

[image: 3 examples of overlays that allow users to apply tags/categories to an item]

I particularly like the gmail example as it's an easy way for users to select multiple labels, but the YNAB search functionality is nice if you expect there to be many possible tags. And assuming users can apply multiple tags, you'd need some sort of "done" or "apply" button.

Comment: I like the Notion example. I hadn't thought of them as an example. Gmail's solution is very common but I worry the list could become too large to scroll on mobile. I do like the YNAB solution to be able to search. Thank you for the examples!